# securing server to server http post

Tags: java, http, web, webserver, firewall

Website is developed on JSF, Servlet.
In my website, I accept data submission from few restricted websites using HTTP POST method. We exchange some secure key to ensure that correct source is sending data.

But is there any way to ensure that the data is submitted from specific domain / IP address only?
In application level I can check

> request.header('Referer')

, but some proxy might hide the referer. Can this configuration done on firewall level?

Eg. Say my website is a payment gateway website, integrated with www.abc.com. I want only abc.com to submit data. So a user using abc.com should be able to submit data to my website only through abc.com, and not any other website.

Comment: In other words there is a form or a link on a page coming from `abc.com` which posts/redirects to your site. This is why you want to check the `Referer`. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes a form from abc.com to post to my website

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) method to verify the client or the last proxy.

Comment: Will this not return end users IP address and not server's ip?

Comment: Isn't it what you're asking for by `the data is submitted from specific domain / IP address only`?

Comment: Added an example to clarify my requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an apache server you could use

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

this. So you could specify which all domains can access your application

Comment: Will this not prevent end user to view the page, instesd of a server unable to submit request?

Comment: I thought you wanted to limit the users accessing the page

Comment: Need to prevent server to server submission, added example in original query above